# Executing child process in express js route

Tags: node.js, express, child-process

I am trying to run a simple child process in my express js route and return a json message with the stdout as the message value.
But for some reason the stdout value is undefined any pointers?

express route code

```
const express = require("express")
const asyncHandler = require("express-async-handler")
const cp = require('child_process')
const router =  express.Router()

router.get("/status", asyncHandler( async (req, res) => {
    
    let msg 

    cp.exec('ls', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
        console.log('#1, exec')
        console.log(stdout)
        msg = stdout
    })

    res.json({message:`${msg}`})
}))

module.exports = router
```

Comment: `res.json` executes before the child process does. Try putting it inside `cp.exec`'s callback at the end. By the way, I wouldn't create a child process for every request; that seems quite inefficient. If you simply want to `ls` why not just use `fs.readDir`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move the response INSIDE the callback.  `cp.exec()` is asycnhronous so it starts up and then continues executing the next lines of code.  The callback is called sometime later.  So, you need to send your response INSIDE the callback.

```
const express = require("express")
const cp = require('child_process')
const router =  express.Router()

router.get("/status", (req, res) => {
    
    cp.exec('ls', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (err) {
             console.log(err);
             res.sendStatus(500);
             return;
        }
        console.log('#1, exec');
        console.log(stdout);
        res.json({message:`${stdout}`});
    })
});


module.exports = router;
```

And, this route handler doesn't seem to have any reason to use `asyncHandler` as there's no `async/await` in use.

And, you should properly handle errors.

Comment: Incase I had  async/await in use for example creating a new record of a model called Log for a mongodb collection `const newLog = await Log.create({})` how would I structure the function

Comment: @JordanRob - If you are awaiting a function that returns a promise, then you can just program serially since there are no asynchronous callbacks involved.

Comment: I had placed the await operation in the previous comment in my child process callback function shown above and got a syntax error for the await keyword, it confused me since the child process function is within an async function

Comment: @JordanRob - Sorry, but I can't help with code I can't see.  You can write a new question with the relevant code if you want further help with your issue using `await`.

Comment: Alright let me do just that I'll plug the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72837798/executing-a-child-process-within-an-async-await-function-under-an-express-js-rou)